# Change header image height wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, header, themes

I am looking to change the image header height on my WordPress site, I am using The Company theme, but I can't seem to figure out the CSSrequired

[My site](http://www.thepowerwithin.org.uk/what-we-offer/)

As you can see there is a clouds image in the header I would like this to go further down the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your header size is mostly informed by the padding on the h1 inside of it. You have a number of options here.

Manually set a height

```
#page-title h1 {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Increase vertical padding for top, bottom, or both:

```
#page-title h1 {
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Others, but this is more or less how I would approach it.

Comment: However, I think what you may actually be looking for is the content to be closer to the header. At least, that's what I would want. For that, decrease the top padding (currently 66px) with something like: #sections > .section:first-of-type {padding-top:50px;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add background-position to your page-title ID.

```
#page-title { background-position: center 50% }
```

Adjust the % to get the result you want. Because it's WordPress, you'll need to add a unique class or ID to prevent adjusting all page-titles.

Comment: Hey I’m pretty new to WordPress where should I put this code, and I’m not sure where or how to add a unique class or ID